# FlatBuffers C# CreateSortedVector and LookUpByKey

Tags: c#, flatbuffers

i want to serialize a Dictionary in FlatBuffers. I know that there is no Dictionary equivalent but according to https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/master/docs/source/JavaCsharpUsage.md you can sort the Vectors by a key field and then search for the key. I downloaded FlatBuffers 1.4 from there Github page and compiled the dll. But when i create the schema and use it in my project, there is no Method CreateSortedVectorOfTables of any kind. Only the normal CreateVector method is available. And i cant seem to find the LookUpByKey method either.

This is my test schema:

```
table value{
    keyname:string (key);
    stringValue:string;
}

table test {
    values:[value];
}
```

Can anyone tell me how i can create a sorted vector?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality was only added last week, so you'll need the tip version rather than 1.4. That should generate a special `CreateSorted` method for `values`.